# How can I set a value to variable using a variable already defined in the code?

Tags: c, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I begin by explaining this code of mine

```
#define __C 130.81
#define __D 146.83
#define __E 164.81
#define __F 174.61
#define __G 196.0
#define __A 220.0
#define __B 246.94


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    double frequency = 440;

    int opt;
    int option_index = 0;

    static struct option long_options[] =
        {
        {"freq",   required_argument,       0, 1},
        ...
    while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "f:v:o:hd:0:", long_options, &option_index)) != -1) {
        printf("%d\n", opt);
        switch (opt) {
        case 1:

            frequency = [[  SOLVE ME PLS  ]]

            break;
        }
    }
```

NOTE: this is just the excerpt and not the real code.

What I want with this CLI is that when I execute: `./bin --freq A`
it would set the variable `frequency = __A` and if `./bin --freq D`, then `frequency = __D`. That's just how simple it is!!.

Comment: Actually, no, that's not so simple!

Comment: Idea 1 (general but more difficult): build an in-memory table in which you can look up e.g. `"D"` and map it to 146.83.  Idea 2 (much simpler): just use an 7-way `if`/`else` tree.

Comment: @steve If you're me, what would you choose that consume little of memory and CPU?

Comment: @HarieAmjari The two ideas I suggested should be almost identical in terms of both memory and CPU.  It's mainly a question of what you're more comfortable implementing.

Comment: In slightly more detail, Idea 1 would look like `struct freqmap { char letter; float freq; };` followed by `struct freqmap freqtab[] = { {'C', 130.81}, {'D', 146.83}, ... };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of `char` and an array of `double`, nicely aligned, and use `strcspn` to find the index:

```c
#include <string.h>
double fq_val[] = {
        130.81, 146.83, 164.81, 174.61, 196.0,  220.0,  246.94, -1
};
char *fq_key =
        "C"     "D"     "E"     "F"     "G"     "A"     "B"
;
static double get_fq(char *key){
        return fq_val[strcspn(fq_key, key)];
}
```

This is using `-1` as the "invalid frequency".

---

You can have the preprocessor build the arrays for you, by defining a macro like `FQ(C, 130.81) FQ(D, 146.83) ...` to use inside the initializer and then defining `FQ(k, v)` as either `#k` or `v,`:

```c
#define FQLIST  \
        FQ(C, 130.81) \
        FQ(D, 146.83) \
        FQ(E, 164.81) \
        FQ(F, 174.61) \
        FQ(G, 196.0) \
        FQ(A, 220.0) \
        FQ(B, 246.94)

char *fq_key =
        #define FQ(k, v)        #k
        FQLIST
        #undef FQ
;
double fq_val[] = {
        #define FQ(k, v)        v,
        FQLIST
        #undef FQ
        -1
};
```

Comment: but I don't quite understand what you wrote "as either #k or v,, and including twice a header containing lines like FQ(C, 130.81), FQ(D, 146.83)"

Comment: I've added an example of the trick -- hopefully OK since I'm not able to test it now.

Comment: There's really no need of a separate header -- but you can also see the version using one in the answer's history.